# How to get the inverse of a link function (using $family$linkinv) on a model stored in a nested tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, tidyverse, purrr

I'm working out the output of a model generated with `glm`. The model output is stored in a nested tibble. I want to calculate confidence interval through the transformation from `type` = "link" to inverse-link (using `$family$linkinv`). However, I can't get it to work with `dplyr::mutate` in a nested tibble because the way of pulling the `$family$linkinv` is from the model object using `model$family$linkinv(x)`, which seems not to work as intended in the nested format.

### Background

This current question is based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63501287/6105259) (and chosen answer) I posted about testing the level of liking fruits by different predictors using a linear model. I conduct a research to figure out which fruit is more likeable: mango, banana, or apple. To this end, I go ahead and sample 100 people at random. I ask them to rate, on a scale of 1-5, the degree of liking each of the fruits.

While the previous question had to do with `lm`, here I'm trying to utilize quasibinomial `glm`. The issue is that I want to get confidence intervals but my method (`glm %>% predict`) outputs SE in "link space", therefore I have to go through a conversion process ([detailed in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424417)) to get what I want.

### Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(123)

fruit_liking_df <-
  data.frame(
    id = 1:100,
    i_love_apple = sample(c(1:5), 100, replace = TRUE),
    i_love_banana = sample(c(1:5), 100, replace = TRUE),
    i_love_mango = sample(c(1:5), 100, replace = TRUE),
    age = sample(c(20:70), 100, replace = TRUE),
    is_male = sample(c(0, 1), 100, prob = c(0.2, 0.8), replace = TRUE),
    education_level = sample(c(1:4), 100, replace = TRUE),
    is_colorblinded = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
  )

> as_tibble(fruit_liking_df)

## # A tibble: 100 x 8
##       id i_love_apple i_love_banana i_love_mango   age is_male education_level is_colorblinded
##    <int>        <int>         <int>        <int> <int>   <dbl>           <int>           <dbl>
##  1     1            3             5            2    50       1               2               0
##  2     2            3             3            1    49       1               1               0
##  3     3            2             1            5    70       1               1               1
##  4     4            2             2            5    41       1               3               1
##  5     5            3             1            1    49       1               4               0
##  6     6            5             2            1    29       0               1               0
##  7     7            4             5            5    35       1               3               0
##  8     8            1             3            5    24       0               3               0
##  9     9            2             4            2    55       1               2               0
## 10    10            3             4            2    69       1               4               0
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

#### I want to test my data in a per cent scale, so first I transform it by subtracting 1 and then dividing by 4:

```r
fruit_liking_df %<>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("i_love_")), ~ subtract(., 1) %>% divide_by(., 4))

> as_tibble(fruit_liking_df)

## # A tibble: 100 x 8
##       id i_love_apple i_love_banana i_love_mango   age is_male education_level is_colorblinded
##    <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <int>   <dbl>           <int>           <dbl>
##  1     1         0.5           1            0.25    50       1               2               0
##  2     2         0.5           0.5          0       49       1               1               0
##  3     3         0.25          0            1       70       1               1               1
##  4     4         0.25          0.25         1       41       1               3               1
##  5     5         0.5           0            0       49       1               4               0
##  6     6         1             0.25         0       29       0               1               0
##  7     7         0.75          1            1       35       1               3               0
##  8     8         0             0.5          1       24       0               3               0
##  9     9         0.25          0.75         0.25    55       1               2               0
## 10    10         0.5           0.75         0.25    69       1               4               0
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

#### Now I use a pipe to run the glm model for each fruit, get SE in link space, and convert SE to CI

```r
## will be needed later
my_new_data_for_pred <- expand_grid(
  age = 45,
  is_male = .5,
  education_level = 2.5,
  is_colorblinded = 0.5
)

## will be needed later
critval <- 1.96

model_fits_grouped <-
  fruit_liking_df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("i_love"), values_to = "fruit") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(model_fit = map(
    data,
    ~ glm(
      data = .x,
      fruit ~ I(age - 45) +
        I((age - 45) ^ 2) +
        I(is_male - .5) +
        I(education_level - 2) +
        is_colorblinded,
      family = quasibinomial
    )
  )) %>%
  mutate(predicted_values = map(
    model_fit,
    ~ bind_cols(my_new_data_for_pred,
                as.data.frame(
                  predict(
                    newdata = my_new_data_for_pred,
                    .x,
                    type = "link",
                    interval = "confidence",
                    level = 0.95,
                    se.fit = T
                  )
                )) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        estimate =  fit,
        lower_ci_link =  fit - critval * se.fit,
        upper_ci_link = fit + critval * se.fit
      )
  ))

> model_fits_grouped

## # A tibble: 3 x 4
## # Groups:   name [3]
##   name          data               model_fit predicted_values 
##   <chr>         <list>             <list>    <list>           
## 1 i_love_apple  <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 x 10]>
## 2 i_love_banana <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 x 10]>
## 3 i_love_mango  <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 x 10]>
```

Unnesting the `predicted_values` gets:

```r
> model_fits_grouped %>% unnest(predicted_values)

## # A tibble: 3 x 13
## # Groups:   name [3]
##   name          data              model_fit   age is_male education_level is_colorblinded     fit se.fit residual.scale estimate lower_ci_link upper_ci_link
##   <chr>         <list>            <list>    <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
## 1 i_love_apple  <tibble [100 x 6~ <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5  0.0843  0.261          0.709   0.0843        -0.427         0.595
## 2 i_love_banana <tibble [100 x 6~ <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 -0.0718  0.286          0.781  -0.0718        -0.633         0.489
## 3 i_love_mango  <tibble [100 x 6~ <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 -0.140   0.279          0.762  -0.140         -0.687         0.407
```

**Here's the problem: Now I want to mutate two more columns *within* `predicted_values` for the inverse-link transformation for `lower_ci_link` and `upper_ci_link`, but this fails**

```r
model_fits_grouped <-
  fruit_liking_df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("i_love"), values_to = "fruit") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(model_fit = map(
    data,
    ~ glm(
      data = .x,
      fruit ~ I(age - 45) +
        I((age - 45) ^ 2) +
        I(is_male - .5) +
        I(education_level - 2) +
        is_colorblinded,
      family = quasibinomial
    )
  )) %>%
  mutate(predicted_values = map(
    model_fit,
    ~ bind_cols(my_new_data_for_pred,
                as.data.frame(
                  predict(
                    newdata = my_new_data_for_pred,
                    .x,
                    type = "link",
                    interval = "confidence",
                    level = 0.95,
                    se.fit = T
                  )
                )) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        estimate =  fit,
        lower_ci_link =  fit - critval * se.fit,
        upper_ci_link = fit + critval * se.fit
      ) %>%
######################### this addition fails ###########################
      mutate(
        lower_ci_inverse_link = model_fit$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link),
        upper_ci_inverse_link = model_fit$family$linkinv(upper_ci_link)
      )
#########################################################################
  ))
```

And I get:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `predicted_values`. x Problem
> with `mutate()` input `lower_ci_inverse_link`. x attempt to apply
> non-function i Input `lower_ci_inverse_link` is
> `model_fit$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link)`. i The error occurred in row
>
> 1. i Input `predicted_values` is `map(...)`. i The error occurred in row 1.

I assume that the problem is that I'm trying to mutate new columns within `predicted_values`, but using `model_fit$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link)` refers to `model_fit` which is in a higher level in the nested tibble.

### Bottom line question

How can I get to mutate inverse-link columns *within* `predicted_values` using `model_fit$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link)` and `model_fit$family$linkinv(upper_ci_link)` to ultimately get (scroll all the way to the rightest two columns):

```r
> model_fits_grouped %>% unnest(predicted_values)

## # A tibble: 3 x 15
## # Groups:   name [3]
##   name          data               model_fit   age is_male education_level is_colorblinded   fit se.fit residual.scale estimate lower_ci_link upper_ci_link lower_ci_inverse_link_*DEMO* upper_ci_inverse_link_*DEMO*
##   <chr>         <list>             <list>    <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>                      <dbl>                      <dbl>
## 1 i_love_apple  <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 0.521 0.0632          0.349    0.521         0.397         0.645                      0.111                      0.111
## 2 i_love_banana <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 0.482 0.0701          0.387    0.482         0.345         0.620                      0.222                      0.222
## 3 i_love_mango  <tibble [100 x 6]> <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 0.465 0.0683          0.377    0.465         0.331         0.599                      0.333                      0.333
```

---

## APPENDIX

**DEMONSTRATION OF HOW I'M ABLE TO GET WHAT I WANT *WITHOUT* A PIPE OR DATAFRAME**

The following method relies on assigning variables for several steps along the way. For the sake of demonstration, it shows how to run the model and get the `$family$linkinv` for just one fruit.

### Data

As before, it's `fruit_liking_df` after doing the arithmetic transformation to decimals, hence:

```r
> as_tibble(fruit_liking_df)

## # A tibble: 100 x 8
##       id i_love_apple i_love_banana i_love_mango   age is_male education_level  is_colorblinded
##    <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <int>   <dbl>           <int>            <dbl>
##  1     1         0.5           1            0.25    50       1               2                0
##  2     2         0.5           0.5          0       49       1               1                0
##  3     3         0.25          0            1       70       1               1                1
##  4     4         0.25          0.25         1       41       1               3                1
##  5     5         0.5           0            0       49       1               4                0
##  6     6         1             0.25         0       29       0               1                0
##  7     7         0.75          1            1       35       1               3                0
##  8     8         0             0.5          1       24       0               3                0
##  9     9         0.25          0.75         0.25    55       1               2                0
## 10    10         0.5           0.75         0.25    69       1               4                0
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

### Model

I'm going to focus only on the `i_love_apple` column data, and run `glm` on it.

```r
my_model <-
  glm(
    i_love_apple ~ 
      I(age - 45) + 
      I((age - 45) ^ 2) + 
      I(is_male - 0.5)  + 
      I(education_level - 2) + 
      I(is_colorblinded - 0.5),
    family = quasibinomial,
    data = fruit_liking_df
  )
```

### Prediction

Now I run `predict()` on `my_model` using prediction data from `my_new_data_for_pred`:

```r
prediction_link_type <- 
  predict(object = my_model,
          newdata = my_new_data_for_pred,
          type = "link",   ## <------------ type = "link" is crucial to note
          interval = "confidence",
          level = 0.95,
          se.fit = TRUE)


> prediction_link_type

## $fit
##          1 
## 0.08427577 

## $se.fit
## [1] 0.2606326

## $residual.scale
## [1] 0.7090294
```

Now I convert from the SE measure I got in `prediction_link_type` to confidence interval (CI) by multiplying the SE by `critval` (which has been assigned with `1.96`). I assign two separate vectors: one with the upper bound CI, and another with the lower bound CI:

```r
lower_ci_link <- prediction_link_type$fit - (critval * prediction_link_type$se.fit)
upper_ci_link <- prediction_link_type$fit + (critval * prediction_link_type$se.fit)
```

Almost there! I got the CI values but they are in "link" space (because `predict()` used `type = "link"`). To convert the CI values back from "link", I use inverse-link function:

```r
lower_ci_inverse_link <- my_model$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link)
upper_ci_inverse_link <- my_model$family$linkinv(upper_ci_link)
```

**In Summary**

Although this "vectors" method gets the job done, it is **not** what I'm looking for. Instead, I want to incorporate the conversion of "link -> SE -> CI -> inverselink" through the pipe introduced in the beginning of this question.

Comment: Would it helpt to add a rowwise() %>% before the mutate? This causes the operation to be evaluated row by row instead of for the whole column and therefore you have a value instead of the vector as input.

Comment: thanks, @pieterbons. I tried adding  an additional `rowwise()` before the broken `mutate`, following your suggestion but it won't work :/

Comment: each value `predicted_values` is a list of 3. `fit`, `se.fit` and `residual.scale`. All 3 of them are numeric vector. There is no `fit$family` present in the first place hence you are getting that an error. Can you show how you run this with an independent example instead of this dataframe?

Comment: thanks, @RonakShah! I've updated the question per your request. I hope this make it clearer.

Comment: I ended up revising the entire question because of wrong code,.

Comment: Your code still does not work and you still have brackets at wrong place. Check the closing bracket of `map(model_fit....`.

Comment: @RonakShah, sorry, it's frustrating. Yes, I omitted the `critval`  and `my_new_data_for_pred` assignment. I corrected it now. However, the brackets seem to be ok. I tried this code on a different machine and it runs well. So it's only about the `$linkinv` issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the data passed in `map` you need to use `.x`. Try the below answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- fruit_liking_df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("i_love"), values_to = "fruit") %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(model_fit = map(
    data,
    ~ glm(
      data = .x,
      fruit ~ I(age - 45) +
        I((age - 45) ^ 2) +
        I(is_male - .5) +
        I(education_level - 2) +
        is_colorblinded,
      family = quasibinomial
    )
  )) %>%
  mutate(predicted_values = map(
    model_fit,
    ~ bind_cols(my_new_data_for_pred,
                as.data.frame(
                  predict(
                    newdata = my_new_data_for_pred,
                    .x,
                    type = "link",
                    interval = "confidence",
                    level = 0.95,
                    se.fit = T
                  )
                )) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        estimate =  fit,
        lower_ci_link =  fit - critval * se.fit,
        upper_ci_link = fit + critval * se.fit,
        lower_ci_inverse_link = .x$family$linkinv(lower_ci_link),
        upper_ci_inverse_link = .x$family$linkinv(upper_ci_link)
    )))
```

`result` looks like  :

```
result
# name          data               model_fit predicted_values 
#  <chr>         <list>             <list>    <list>           
#1 i_love_apple  <tibble [100 × 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 × 12]>
#2 i_love_banana <tibble [100 × 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 × 12]>
#3 i_love_mango  <tibble [100 × 6]> <glm>     <tibble [1 × 12]>
```

To get all the values as separate columns you can use `unnest_wider` :

```
result %>% unnest_wider(predicted_values)

#  name  data  model_fit   age is_male education_level is_colorblinded     fit se.fit
#  <chr> <lis> <list>    <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 i_lo… <tib… <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5  0.0843  0.261
#2 i_lo… <tib… <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 -0.0718  0.286
#3 i_lo… <tib… <glm>        45     0.5             2.5             0.5 -0.140   0.279
# … with 6 more variables: residual.scale <dbl>, estimate <dbl>, lower_ci_link <dbl>,
#   upper_ci_link <dbl>, lower_ci_inverse_link <dbl>, upper_ci_inverse_link <dbl>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! But do you see why this works for you but didn't in my case? I fail to find the key difference. I've revised the code in the question so now it's running smoothly (except for the broken lines the question is about).

Comment: The key difference which I can immediately spot are 1) I don't know why you are doing `bind_cols(my_new_data_for_pred,...` I think it fails for me because of that at that line. 2) When you are doing `estimate =  fit` or `lower_ci_link =  fit - critval * se.fit` it doesn't know what `fit` or `se.fit` is. You probably mean to use `predicted_values$fit` and same for `se.fit`. In my answer I use `map_dbl` to extract those values and include it as separate column but you don't have that column so you cannot directly refer them like that.

Comment: Thanks. This is based on a solution I adopted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63502317/6105259. And somehow it _does_ know how to do `lower_ci_link =  fit - critval * se.fit` without needing to specify `predicted_values$fit`. The code (now corrected) in the question in this post also uses the same principle and works for me without explicit reference to `predicted_values$fit`.

Comment: Sorry for the hassle, but I had to revise the entire question because there was an error of wrong parenthesis placement in my model which threw off the entire code. Would you please consider looking at the question with a fresh eye? The code has to run well now (fingers crossed). Regardless, the thing not working for me with your solution is that I need `lower_ci_inverse_link` and `upper_ci_inverse_link` to be _within_ `predicted_values`.The question now asks that directly. Thanks.

Comment: @Emman Check updated answer. Maybe that is what you were looking for.